# Отрицание регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать отрицание регулярного выражения для определения 3х или больше повторяющихся символов?

```
(.)\\1{2}
/(.)\1\1/
```

Comment: Можете привести пример строки, что в ней должно быть найдено и что не должно быть? Или короткий пример кода, для которого нужно такое выражение.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt password - валидная строка, passsword - не валидная, это для валидации пароля, в котором не должно быть повторяющихся символов. 111passs - не валидный, 11pass - валидный

Comment: А нельзя использовать что-то вроде: `const notValid = /(.)\1\1/i.test('passsword');` или `const valid = !/(.)\1\1/i.test('passsword');`?

Comment: @Vladyslav Tereshyn проверяйте строку на невалидность, как в комментарии выше подсказали, только с учетом трёх и более повторяющихся символов -  `(.)\1{2,}.test('passsword')`

Comment: а если это будет слово `niceeeee`? нужно регулярное выражение

Comment: @Vladyslav Tereshyn `/(.)\1{2,}/i.test('Любааааая строка')`

Comment: @Doigrales :), я понимаю как это делать )) но мне нужно добавить отрицание во внутрь регулярного выражения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение не находит соответствия, если более 2-х одинаковых символов подряд:

```
const isValid = /^(?:(?!(.)\1{2,}).)+$/.test('passsword');
console.log(isValid); //false
```

Проверить здесь https://regex101.com/r/TqIGf8/2